# Куда пропали значения chart?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть буквы(слева в DGV). Я подгружаю в chart частоту букв в тексте, но у меня не вмещаются все подписи. Как уменьшить интервал или просто вернуть подписи[image: введите сюда описание изображения]? 
Кусок кода, отвечающий за загрузку в chart:

```
    private void LoadGraph()
    {

        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.StackedBar;
        var kek = hk.countDict.Keys.ToList();
        kek.Sort();
        foreach (var item in kek)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(item, hk.countDict[item]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это автоматическая  разметка осей. Вам нужно руками настроить параметры отображения осей, в частности интервал. Настройки осей искать внутри ChartArea

Comment: @rdom Не получается

Comment: для оси X задайте интервал 1. У графика типа Bar, оси перевернуты: X - вверх, Y - вправо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы отображались все метки, необходимо выставить значение интервала на нужной оси. Для графиков типа `Bar` в контроле `Chart` оси X и Y меняются местами, поэтому интервал нужно выставлять для оси X, если нужно видеть все подписи Bar-ам (по вертикальной оси).

Небольшой демонстрационный фрагмент ниже.

```
var rnd = new Random();
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bar;
string labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
foreach(var c in labels)
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(c.ToString(), rnd.Next(0, 30));
}
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
```

Разумеется данные нужно подставить из вашего источника данных и оформить код как полагается, со всеми проверками на null и т.д.

Comment: На удивление сработало, хотя вчера не получалось